# What causes typeorm Operand should contain 1 column(s) error?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am developing a nest project with typeorm, i have two tables car and user. I would like to write a query with typeorm which is similar to a nested sql query.
My code currently looks like this:

```
    const queryBuilder = this.carRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('car')
    .select('car.id')
    .where(qb => {
        const subQuery = qb.subQuery()
            .select("car.id")
            .from(Car, "car")
            .leftJoinAndSelect('car.users', 'user')
            .andWhere('user.status = :status', { status: StatusEnum.Active })
            .getQuery();
       return subQuery;
    });
```

Unfortunately I get ***Operand should contain 1 column(s)*** error. I already tried to write this query several ways, but I couldn't make it work yet.
Later I would want to expand this query with other conditions based on the query params that came from the request.
I imagine something like this:

```
    const queryBuilder = this.carRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('car')
    .select('car.id')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('car.users', 'users')
    .where(qb => {
        const subQuery = qb.subQuery()
            .select("car.id")
            .from(Car, "car")
            .leftJoinAndSelect('car.users', 'user')
            .andWhere('user.status = :status', { status: StatusEnum.Active })

            if (query?.make) {
            subQuery.andWhere('car.make = :make', { make: query.make });
            }

            if (query?.model) {
            subQuery.andWhere('car.model = :model', { model: query.model });
            }

            .getQuery();
       return subQuery;
    })
    .leftJoin('car.carDetail', 'carDetail')

    if (query?.search) {
      queryBuilder.andWhere(
        new Brackets((qb) => {
          qb.where(
            `
            carDetail.country like :search OR 
            carDetail.city like :search OR 
            `,
            {
              search: `%${query.search}%`,
            },
          );
        }),
      );
    }

    return queryBuilder.getMany();
```

So I want to filter the result of the subquery in the outer query. Am I totally worng? How shoud I approach this?
Where can I find help with writing queries like this?